# java перевод ввода пользователем "C7" в int

Tags: java

Изучаю джаву. Решил сделать морской бой "сложным" путём, чтобы обучиться некоторым вещам. Игра будет спрашивать клетку, в которую должна выстрелить пушка. Нужно перевести вводимую строку в int, так как все клетки пронумерованы в int.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, для стандартного поля 10х10, будет сквозная нумерация, т.е., А1 имеет номер 01, А2 - 02... B1 - 11... J10 - 100.
Тогда после валидации разбиваем координату на букву (char) и цифру (int).

```
String coord = "C7"; // например, получили C7
char ch = coord.charAt(0);
// Тут можно проверить получился ли символ из допустимого диапазона

int number = Integer.parseInt(coord.charAt(1));
int absoluteCoord = 10 * (ch - 'A') + number;
```

Как-то так

Comment: 1) 10 уже не digit, а number:) `int number = Integer.parseInt(coord.charAt(1))` 2) сдаётся мне где-то должно быть умножение на 10: `((ch - 'A') * 10) + number`? или так `((ch - 'A') * 10) + (number - 1)` для нумерации с нуля?

Comment: @Sergey да, наверное. В телефоне писал, просто общую идею накидал. Только не на 10 умножать, а на размер поля по горизонтали (если поле нестандартное)